# I have installed flutter in E drive but android studio in C drive. will it work?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-doctor

I had installed Android studio in C drive for developing using java, but now I want to install flutter, and I have installed it in E drive. But when running `flutter doctor`, I get the following error:
error after running flutter doctor

[image]

It says I need to accept android licenses using `flutter doctor --android-licenses` which I did, but got threading exception, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you should properly set the path as in this documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path

To resolve the error command `flutter doctor --android-licences`

Comment: Actually I did, but didn't solve the error

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by installing `android SDK command-line tools`.

- Go to the android studio setting and install `android SDK command-line tools`

[image]

- Also after doing these steps go to `E drive flutter SDK location` and
  run `flutter_console.bat` file in which enter these commands:

> `flutter doctor`
>
> `flutter doctor --android-licenses`